# What makes PHP unset form variables?

Tags: php, forms

My HTML code:

```
<form class="well" name="login" action="text.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" class="span3" id="username" name"username" placeholder="Enter your valid email">
<input type="text" class="span3" id="password" name"password" placeholder="Enter your password">
<button type="submit" class="btn" >Enzemble </button>
</form>
      <h2>New User? ... Register</h2>
        <form class="well" name="register" action="register.php" method="post" >
            <input type="text" class="span3" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your valid email" onBlur="emailValidation()">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Enter Enzemble!</button>
        </form>
```

The bottom form works fine.

The top code gives "undefined index" notice and does not read values of username and password in text.php
The text.php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($email)) $email=$_POST["username"];
if (isset($password)) $password=$_POST["pasword"];
echo "username " . $email . "password " . $password;
?>
```

The error:
Notice: Undefined index: pasword in /home/nitin/www/enzemble/text.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined variable: email in /home/nitin/www/enzemble/text.php on line 9 username password

I am not getting html form values in php. This is surprising. I am working on it for a long time. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your HTML code. It's missing a `=` for the `name` attribute of the input fields:

```
<input type="text" class="span3" id="username" name"username" placeholder="Enter your valid email">
HERE ----------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you wrote `pasword` instead of `password`. Try it with

```
if (isset($password)) $password=$_POST["password"];
```

Anyway, you should check for `$_POST['password']` instead just for `$password`

See [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php):

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

You are just checking if the *variables* `$email` and `$password` are set, but they aren't set yet, right? So either you meant to negate your checks:

```
if (!isset($email)) $email=$_POST["username"];
if (!isset($password)) $password=$_POST["password"];
```

Or you meant to check that the $_POST fields were set:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) $email=$_POST["username"];
if (isset($_POST['password'])) $password=$_POST["password"];
```

Comment: I tried with this code:
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
    {
        $email=$_POST['username'];
        echo "The email is " . $email;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password']))
    {

    $email=$_POST['password'];
    echo "The password is " . $password;
    }
Now the screen is blank, isset returns false. 
I am using default php in Ubuntu, so I would suggest someone to just copy the code and test.

Comment: Gattoo, I've added another answer because I think it targets a different part of your question. The reason nobody is copying your code to actually try it is because that takes time, and we are not your troubleshooting consultants.

Comment: Thank you Emil for your suggestion. The code started working.
The community at StackOverflow is far more than any consultancy company. We are a great community, like siblings. Please don't have hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

$password not exists yet, check $_POST["pasword"] in `isset`, not $password.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's wrapped in another `<form></form>` wrap everything in one form.

Like:

```
  <form class="well" name="register" action="register.php" method="post" >
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your valid email" onBlur="emailValidation()" />
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your valid email" />
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Enter Enzemble!</button>
    </form>
```

Edit: And update php script like **Emil** suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($password)) $password=$_POST["pasword"];
```

You're spelling password in `$_POST["pasword"]` with just one s.